# Canning the ccna tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [ccna](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ccna) tag seems to either be "I saw this question in an exam" IE - not a actual problem or dosen't really add to the searchability of a question. There's 7 instances of it, a good chunk of which may be closed or deleted. Should we can this tag?